# Apache commons sftp - go above user home directory

Tags: java, sftp, apache-commons, apache-commons-vfs

We have a server which uses the following convention:

```
/pathA/Users/
/pathB/data/
```

When users log in they end up at the respective `/pathA/Users/user/` dir, but they sometimes need to access `/pathB/data/` . I want to write a browser that, using sftp, would let users browse content of the server (I would be happy to find a java tool for that I could just plug into my application, but failed to find anything that matches all my requirements).
The problem I have is that `apache-commons-vfs` accepts a string of form

```
sftp://user:password@host
```

and uses that to log into the user directory and **treat that directory as a root**. The effect is that I can't step above that dir, calling `getParent()` on corresponding `FileObject` returns `null`. I know it is possible to step above the user home dir using sftp over terminal, so I guess this is a limitation imposed by `apache-commons-vfs` library. Would anyone happen to know if I can go around that problem so that browsing around the whole server would be possible?

Comment: *browsing around the whole server* ... are you sure? you can always SSH to the server.

Comment: I sure get your point, but I need the access to some dirs outside of user dirs. The whole point of the application is to make life easier for users that start shaking at the sound of word 'terminal', so I don't want them to have to dab at ssh. And I can get the functionality I want using ssh from my code, but hope to find a library that will spare me the coding effort.

Comment: Should anyone in the future be interested: I was able to get the functionality I need with `SSHJ's StatefulSFTPClient`, although it's a bit of a work as its documentation is a bit scarce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you actually can. check this code!

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(opts, "no");
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, false);
        FileSystemManager fileSystemManager = VFS.getManager();
        FileObject fileObject = fileSystemManager
                .resolveFile("sftp://user:password@host/",opts);

        // foo is under SERVER ROOT not USER's!!!

        FileObject temp = fileObject.resolveFile("/foo/faa/frog/");
        FileObject fileObjects[] = temp.getChildren();

        try {
            for (FileObject j : fileObjects) {

                System.out.println(j.getName().getBaseName());
                j.close();
            }
        } finally {
            fileObject.close();
            temp.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha, I never thought of just trying an absolute path. Clever.